# Custom specialization of `std::basic_string<>`

Tags: c++, template-specialization

Let us assume I have a special character type, `myChar`, which is distinct from the existing standard character classes (`char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`) used as specializations of `std::basic_string<>`.

Let us also assume that the features provided by `std::basic_string< myChar >` are *almost* all that I need. I just want two, three functions in addition to what that template already provides.

Let us also assume I have somewhat limited experience with *programming* templates (as opposed to using them, which I do all day).

**How would I go about spezializing a standard template, expanding it with additional functions?**

I have a feeling it should be a matter of just a few lines, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Have you studied the implementation of `vector<bool>` and concluded that it consists of "only a few lines" extra?

Comment: @KerrekSB: No I haven't, since I am aware that `vector< bool >` changes much more, *internally*, than just adding a couple of functions, *externally*, and as such I think it doesn't really apply to my problem.

Comment: A specialization is a whole new class, and you have to implement *everything* again, unfortunately. However, if you just have a new character type - without any extra string functions - the right place is to specialize `char_traits<myChar>`, a much smaller class.

Comment: @BoPersson: Bummer. I thought it would be possible to just implement the *additional* functionality, relying on the `basic_string<>` template to do the rest. Unfortunately, the traits aren't enough for my needs.

Comment: If this had been your own template, you could of course have moved common functionality to a base class and derived all the variants from that. Doesn't work for existing std classes though.

Comment: @BoPersson: Since this was apparently barking up the wrong tree, you think I should delete the question?

Comment: Not necessarily. A record of that something doesn't work can also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bo Persson pointed out, there is no way to partially expand a template this way without reimplementing all of it.